# Ошибка при конвертации xml в xls. Как правильно прописать путь до моего файла?

Tags: excel, vba

**Задача**: конвертировать xml в xls

**Проблема**: вылезает ошибка "строка 2, символ 11, ошибка: "Предполагается наличие окончания конструкции", код: 800A0401". Когда везде удаляю As String и подобные, то всё заканчивается без ошибок, но ничего не происходит. А я ожидаю, чтобы файл xml сконвертировался в файл xls.

**Вопрос**: Как правильно прописать путь до моего файла? Он вот так выглядит:

`C:\Program Files\Новая папка2`

```vb
Sub XMLTOCSV()
Dim f, p As String
Dim s As Integer

p = "C:\Program Files\Новая папка2\"
f = Dir(p & "*.xml")
s = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        s = s + 1
        ConvertXMLtoXLS p & f, p & Replace(f, ".xml", "") & ".xls"
        f = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoXLS(xmlFile, xlsFile)
Dim xlAppAs Application
Dim xlBook As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
xlBook.SaveAs xlsFile, 6
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Чего-то Вы намудрили... `p = Dir("C:\Program Files\Новая папка2" & "\*.xml")`, потом `f = Dir(p & "*.xml")`. Чему теперь равняется строка `p & f`?

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. Можете подсказать как правильно прописать этот путь? `"C:\Program Files\Новая папка2\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обработать один файл, не нужен цикл, все намного проще. Конвертируем test.xml в test.xlsx

```
Sub XMLtoXLSX()
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = "C:\Program Files\Новая папка2\test.xml"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call ConvertXMLtoXLSX(sPath, Replace(sPath, ".xml", "") & ".xlsx")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoXLSX(xmlFile, xlsxFile)
    With Application.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
        .SaveAs fileName:=xlsxFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Поправил, но всё равно не работает. Жалуется на вторую строку, пишет о том, что предполагается наличие окончания инструкции. Когда везде удаляю эти строки As Integer и так далее, то у всё проходит хорошо, но программа не работает. Я думал, что она сконвертирует из файла xml файл xls.

Comment: Изменил сообщение